# Add Unique Names from List to Create Columns in Dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I currently have the below list and am trying to develop a data frame from the results. Essentially, I would like to take the first list and add it to a new data frame, creating columns with variable names, and storing the results in the first row. Then move to the next list and create a new `y` column so that any variables with `y` results would be added to that list.

```
list
[[1]]
       x       xy 
1.000365 1.000365 

[[2]]
       x        y 
1.007184 1.007184 

[[3]]
       x        y 
1.020803 1.020803

[[4]]
   NA
```

Is this possible to do? I've been trying to figure out how a `for loop` or `lapply` might work in this scenario but am unsure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[` in `lappy` on `unique` `names` of the vectors:

```
i <- unique(unlist(lapply(x, names)))
setNames(as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(x, `[`, i))), i)
#         x       xy        y
#1 1.000365 1.000365       NA
#2 1.007184       NA 1.007184
#3 1.020803       NA 1.020803
#4       NA       NA       NA
```

Data:

```
x <- list(c(x=1.000365, xy=1.000365), c(x=1.007184, y=1.007184),
          c(x=1.020803, y=1.020803), NA)
```

Answer (score 1):

lapply, or even better bind_rows would be good for this:

```r
library(dplyr)
d <- bind_rows( your.list )
```

Note, I assume the `xy` name of the 2nd element of the first list entry is a typo?

Comment: `xy` is the name of another variable in the list. So it would be a new column in the data frame. I've added another list to include an `NA` entry as well. Ideally I'd make a data frame which contains a column of `n` from `1-4` and just put `NA` in the fourth row.

Comment: well, bind_rows handles different names just fine, but it doesn't handle the 4th NA